# Akka actor read state from database

Tags: akka, actor, nonblocking

I would like to ask for pattern when it is required to init actor state from database. I have a DAO which return Future[...] and normaly to be non blocking message should be send to actor on future complete. But this case is different. I cannot receive any message from actor mailbox before initialization complete. Is the only way to block actor thread while waiting for database future complete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most trivial approach would be to define two receive methods, e.g. `initializing` and `initialized`, starting with `def receive = initializing`. Inside your `inizializing` context, you could simply send back a message like `InitializationNotReady` to tell the other actor that he should try it again later. After your actor is initialized, you switch your context with `context become initialized` to the new state, where you can operate normally.

After all, another good aproach could be to have a look at [Akka Persistence](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/persistence.html). It enables stateful actors to persist their internal state so that it can be recovered when an actor is started, restarted after a JVM crash or by a supervisor, or migrated in a cluster.

In you case, you can restore your state from a database, since their are multiple storage options for Akka persistence. you can find them [here](http://akka.io/community/#plugins-to-akka-persistence). After that recovery, you can receive messages like you're used to it.

Comment: Akka persistence looks good for my case, but I don't need event sourcing and additional storage for snapshot. I would like to read a snapshot from my exisitng table, is it possible? Changing actor state not match to my use case, because messages will be send from regular code (fire and forget) not from separate actor.

Comment: Then you can try if `stash` helps in your case. When starting your actor, all of the incoming messages can be stashed. After the initialization is complete, you can unstash all received messages, so that it looks like they all received now. You can read about stashing in the docs http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html#Stash